# Error : org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.team.ui

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm trying to run project as eclipse application in Luna eclipse version. I'm getting below issue. I tried configuring SWT libraries also, but it is not working. Could you please help me with this?

```
   ENTRY org.eclipse.team.ui 4 0 2016-08-11 11:40:09.466
    !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
    !STACK 0
    org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.team.ui [1]
      Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.3.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
        -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.10.2.v20141118-1227"; singleton:="true"
           org.eclipse.ui.ide [36]
             Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.106.0,4.0.0)"
               -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.106.1.v20141002-1150"; singleton:="true"
                  org.eclipse.ui [11]
                    Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.105.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                      -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.106.2.v20150204-1030"; singleton:="true"
                         org.eclipse.ui.workbench [9]
                           Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.annotation; version="1.0.0"
      Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.5.0,4.0.0)"
        -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.106.1.v20141002-1150"; singleton:="true"

        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some plug-ins requesting Eclipse 3 versions of plug-ins. You need to look through your the required versions in your plug-in dependencies and adjust them to all Eclipse 4.

Comment: I have changed plugins version in manifest.mf file. But Still I'm getting same errros